# Stop Mail app from importing mails from transfer so we can use app from scratch

Tags: mail.app, email, data-transfer

My husband took over my 2017 Macbook Air 13 inch three months ago. We transferred everything from his 2011 iMac via Time Machine.

We just tried to open the Mail app today (he normally uses Gmail). First we got a message stating *"Mail needs to import your messages"*. Then we got a message saying *"The import failed. An error occurred during the import. Make sure you have available space in your home folder and try again."*

We don't want to import the emails. We'd like to start using Mail app from scratch, but the Mail app quits when we cancel the import. This means we can't set it up for him to use. Is there any way to stop the import so we can use the Mail app "fresh"? We're using OS Monterey 12.7.2. Thanks.

UPDATE: We've decided just to install Thunderbird and use that app for emails. It's easier than trying to figure out Apple Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to start Apple Mail "fresh" by deleting the entire `~/Library/Mail` folder.

To do this from Finder:

1. Make sure Apple Mail is not running.
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
3. Type or copy & paste: `~/Library/` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. In the window that opens, scroll until you see the **Mail** folder.
5. Drag this folder to your Trash.

If you're up for doing it from Terminal, it's fewer steps:

1. Just type `rm -rf ~/Library/Mail`

Once you've done this, try launching **Mail.app**. It should be in a factory default state.

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much! Your solution worked!

Comment: @GrandmaGloss I'm glad. Please mark it as a solution if you can.

Comment: Done.:-) It's the green checkmark, right?